# $((I \cap J)^{-1})^{-1} = (I^{-1})^{-1} \cap (J^{-1})^{-1}$ for ideals of an integral domain?

Tags: commutative-algebra

> Let $A$ be an integral domain and $I$, $J$ be non-zero ideals.
> Is $((I \cap J)^{-1})^{-1} = (I^{-1})^{-1} \cap (J^{-1})^{-1}$?

For an ideal $I$, we define $I^{-1} = \{x \in K \mid xI \subset A\}$, where $K$ is the field of fractions of $A$.

The motivation came from van der Waerden's Algebra, the section 105: the ideal theory on a Noetherian integrally closed domain.
See [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1187734).

Answer (score 0):

For an integrally closed domain $D,\,$ the $v$-operation $\, I\mapsto I^v = (I^{-1})^{-1}$ distributes over finite intersections of finitely generated fractional ideals iff $D$ is a $v$-domain, see Prop. $6.1$ in  M. Fontana and M. Zafrullah, [On v-domains: a survey.](http://arxiv.org/abs/0902.3592)

$v$-domains are generalizations of Krull and Prufer domains. In your special case of Noetherian domains we have that a domain is a $v$-domain $\iff$ integrally-closed $\iff$ Krull.

Comment: $A$ is not assumed to be integrally closed or noetherian.