# On ideal quotient of intersection of fractional ideals

Tags: ring-theory, commutative-algebra, modules, ideals, integral-domain

Let $R$ be an integral domain with fraction field $K$. For a fractional ideal $I$ (i.e. $I$ is an $R$-submodule of $K$ such that $\exists 0\ne r\in R $ with $rI \subseteq R$) of $R$, define $(R:I)=\{x\in K : xI \subseteq R\}$.

> Is it true that $(R:I\cap J)=(R:I)+(R:J)$ for $I,J$ fractional ideals?

I can easily see that $(R:I)+(R:J) \subseteq (R:I\cap J)$, however I am having difficulty proving $(R:I\cap J) \subseteq (R:I)+(R:J)$.

Comment: I don't think so. If one denotes $(R:I)$ by $I^{-1}$, and suppose that your claim is true, then $((I\cap J)^{-1})^{-1}=(I^{-1}+J^{-1})^{-1}$, that is, $((I\cap J)^{-1})^{-1}=(I^{-1})^{-1}\cap (J^{-1})^{-1}$, which doesn't hold in general; see [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1188937/i-cap-j-1-1-i-1-1-cap-j-1-1-for-ideals-of-an-int/1189007#1189007).

Comment: @user26857: I see ... is it at least true when $R$ is Noetherian / normal ?

Comment: @user26857: I don't think the counterexample you refer to doesn't quite apply here ... $I,J$ in my case are fractional ideals ...

Comment: The characterization given in the linked thread involves fractional ideals.

Comment: According to the paper in the link on v-domains, R would be a v-domain (and I believe your identity would then hold) if R were noetherian and integrally closed.